# How to use ASP.NET to render HTML pages from within another assembly?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, render

I am running the executable application (a `WinForms` one) and I have faced the need to render several HTML pages (kind of "active" - it consumes the model and produces the HTML code of the whole page).

I am looking to the referencing the MVC or ASP.NET project. What is the best way to use these (or maybe other tools; if so, they what are they?) projects to render raw HTML code from the model and some sort of `View Page`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the following SO question about hosting ASP.Net in WinForms projects - its entirely doable!

[Hosting ASP.NET within my application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1365344/hosting-asp-net-within-my-application)

In reply to AgentFires comment about doing it without a http host involved (which Im assuming he means a web server), try these two articles from Rick Strahl about hosting the ASP.Net runtime directly.

http://www.west-wind.com/presentations/aspnetruntime/aspnetruntime.asp

http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2005/Jul/20/AspNET-Runtime-Hosting-Update

They are fairly old, but they should get you started.

Comment: Is there any solutions without http hosting involved?

Answer (score 0):

If your are getting a html string back, then you can injec that html code into the browser control

Comment: Is there any solutions without browser involved? I just need the resulting HTML code, no more. To put it into the zip folder.